# Using bokeh in Python: timeseries

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a plot with bars in bokeh and when zooming in out the x-axis to scale. I am kinda stack how to do it. I am using the following code:

```
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.models import Range1d

def GenerateTimeSeries(StartTime,points):
    valuesStart = [int(c) for c in StartTime.split('-')]
    startT = datetime.datetime(valuesStart[0], valuesStart[1], valuesStart[2], valuesStart[3], valuesStart[4])
    start = time.mktime(startT.timetuple())
    dt =24*3600
    Time = np.linspace(start,start + points*dt, points) * 1000  
    R= np.random.choice(range(0,255),len(Time))
    TimeSeries = pd.DataFrame({'R': R,'time':Time})
    return TimeSeries


timeSeries = GenerateTimeSeries('2015-12-21-0-0',100)
TOOLS = 'xpan,xwheel_zoom'#TOOLS = 'box_select,crosshair,resize,reset'
output_file('Figure.html',title = 'Title')        
p= figure(title = 'Title',x_axis_label='time',plot_width=800,plot_height=500,x_range=Range1d(timeSeries.time[0],timeSeries.time[10]),y_range=Range1d(0,300),tools=TOOLS,x_axis_type = "datetime")#
```

The 'inspiration' of how to make the `GenerateTimeSeries` function come from the following link of the documentation of bokeh:[TimeSeriesPloting](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/correlation.html)

Now if use the `line` plot the result seems to be ok:

```
p.line(timeSeries.time, timeSeries.R, color='#1F78B4', legend='ACME')
show(p)
```

But when using the`rect`:

```
p.rect(x=timeSeries.time[i],y=256/2,width=100,height=256,color='#1F78B4',alpha=0.4)# I want the bar to have a constant height, in case you are wondering why I have the `y` constant.
show(p)
```

The result in the `rect` are some bars with really really small width and hige distance to each other. How can I scale in order the bars to be close to each other?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error lies in the following line:

```
p.rect(x=timeSeries.time[i],y=256/2,width=100,height=256,color='#1F78B4',alpha=0.4)
```

because width is 100 (in the x coordinate system) means 100 seconds (not pixels). So this resutls just in a tiny fraction of your whole x_range

```
dt =24*3600
Time = np.linspace(start,start + points*dt, points) * 1000
```